# Python 3.x Pandas Matplotlib Ignore non float dtype in series (ignore mixed data)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a program that browses for an excel file in the local directory, loads the selected file, then looks for all cells within a certain limit of columns after a certain number of rows (only columns C-G after row 2 for example. The problem is, all of the data should be floats, but they're mixed with strings and datetime. I'm completely happy ignoring anything that isn't a float as the strings are usually notes typed in as a warning, and the dates are usually user error and not data that is needed.

Before it plots the data it takes the 5 columns and combines them into a 1-D dataframe. What I would like to do is iterate through the dataframe and throw out the data that doesn't match. I can pseudo it, but for some reason I can't wrap my head around the actual coding of it.

```
for each in df:
    if df[x].dtype != float64:
        continue
    else
        df2 += df[x]
        continue
```

I know there's a simple way to do this, I just can't figure it out for the life of me.

Any help is greatly appreciated. TIA!

EDIT:

I found out it's actually a series not a dataframe.

I tried adding the following code, but I'm getting that my values are ranging from 0 to 1000 when they should all be well within 0.5 of each other.

`data = pd.to_numeric(data, errors='coerce').dropna()`

Edit 2:

Example code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_excel('testdata.xlsx', header=None)

data = data.stack()

data = pd.to_numeric(data, errors='coerce').dropna()

plt.violinplot(data)
plt.show()
```

The output shows a graph between 0.0000 and 0.0005 on the Y axis and 0.8 and 1.2 on the x axis. The x axis is relatively expected with the small sample size provided, but the y axis is expected to be larger (between 3.5-3.7 or more).

Sample data is in an excel file, although I assume a csv would be input the same. Row and Column headers included so you can replicate if needed.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [3.615, 3.6155, "hello", 3.6153, 1/3/1900]}
```

Paste bin of full code:  https://pastebin.com/ycfsK6gc
Drive link for sample xlsx:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11Tp91y33OmhXsZYg3lL-I3XMXoZl7xuc/edit?usp=drivesdk&ouid=104875635689576986452&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(data, errors='coerce')` is the definitely standard way to do this, so this will be hard for users to answer without a reproducible example.

Comment: @tdy updated original post with code that runs. I will also post a link to a pastebin of the full code.

Comment: Code is not enough to reproduce, input data is necessary as well.

Comment: @Franco Piccolo figured out a way to share that as well.

Comment: thanks @AndrewMorrow, the way you usually share data is trough a code sample that doesn't need an external link. For example: df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1, 2, 3]}

Comment: @Franco Piccolo no problem. I have updated the sample data to the syntax/format suggested. I thought it would be easier to replicate using the file as well.